# Check if array has a value, add class if doesn't

Tags: express, pug

I have a list of category names that are written in Jade.

```
ul
    li Discussion
    li Movie
    li Music
    li Performance
    li Dance
    li Theatre
```

And I have some json, that shows what kind of categories are added to a specific event:

```
…
values: [
{
    ordinal: 50469,
    db_value: 626,
    id: 50469,
    value: "Discussion"
},
{
    ordinal: 50470,
    db_value: 623,
    id: 50470,
    value: "Dance"
}
],
…
```

I have a route, that gets the category values:

```
res.render("event", {
            categories: data.result.properties.category.values
        })
```

How can I achieve an outcome like this, that an if/else checks if the value equals the same thing that's in the li tag and by this adds a class .unactive, if it doesn't exhist in the json array:

```
<ul>
    <li>Discussion</li>
    <li class="unactive">Movie</li>
    <li class="unactive">Music</li>
    <li class="unactive">Performance</li>
    <li>Dance</li>
    <li class="unactive">Theatre</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as [Andrew did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438006/3187556), i would simplify the data format. You could either do this in Node before sending it to the template, or using some JS in the template itself. I'll only edit the template here:

```
- categoryNames = categories.map(function(c){return c.value});
```

This will create an array of just the names. (And, it doesn't even need underscore.js. ;))

Now, you can simply check if a given name is in the array using `indexOf()`:

```
ul
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf("Discussion") > -1 ? "" : "inactive")) Discussion
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf("Movie") > -1 ? "" : "inactive")) Movie
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf("Music") > -1 ? "" : "inactive")) Music
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf("Performance") > -1 ? "" : "inactive")) Performance
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf("Dance") > -1 ? "" : "inactive")) Dance
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf("Theatre") > -1 ? "" : "inactive")) Theatre
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'm glad I could get you 90% of the way there ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would first massage the data a bit to a format that's easier to render, like this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var categoryNames = _.map(data.result.properties.category.values, function(value) {
    return value.value;
});

// categoryNames is an array like this: ['Discussion', 'Dance']

res.render("event", {
    categoryNames: categoryNames
})
```

Now you can get the behavior you're looking for like this:

```
ul
  each category in categoryNames
    li category
```

But if you really want to keep the "disabled" cateogry tags around, you can do it with an inline conditional like this:

```
ul
  each category in ['Discussion', 'Movie', 'Music', 'Performance', 'Theatre']
    li(class=(categoryNames.indexOf(category) === -1) ? "" : "inactive") #{category}
```

Comment: Your code is a start, but it looks like it will output the entire list for every item in `categoryNames`.

Comment: Whoops, removed the each in the second jade template, good eye.

Comment: But now you don't have a `category` variable. I'm afraid the only proper solution is mine. ;)